# How to filter list of strings over nested lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to iterate over a list of filenames and check each string against a set of keys in a dictionary.

In my file sorter, I would like to sort files based on keywords in their filename.
In a next step I need to move the files to a folder based on the found key values.

```
file_list = [
    '01012007-1_employer_finance.txt',
    '25102013-2_cargo_manifest.txt',
    '12022018-3_epmloyer_home_adress.txt',
    '12022028-4_epmloyer_work_adress.txt',
    '01012011-5_employer_finance.txt'
    '01012007-12_employer_finance.txt',
    '25102013-23_cargo_manifest.txt',
    '12022018-34_epmloyer_home_adress.txt',
    '12022028-45_epmloyer_work_adress.txt',
    '01012011-56_employer_finance.txt'
    ]

filelist = {
'file1':'01012007-1_employer_finance.txt',
'file2':'25102013-2_cargo_manifest.txt',
'file3':'12022018-3_epmloyer_home_adress.txt',
'file4':'12022028-4_epmloyer_work_adress.txt',
'file5':'01012011-5_employer_finance.txt',
'file6':'01012007-12_employer_finance.txt',
'file7':'25102013-23_cargo_manifest.txt',
'file8':'12022018-34_epmloyer_home_adress.txt',
'file9':'12022028-45_epmloyer_work_adress.txt',
'file10':'01012011-56_employer_finance.txt'
}

"""Dictionary files"""
filters = {
    'finance': ['employer','finance'],
    'manifest': ['manifest'],
    'address': ['epmloyer', 'adress', 'home'],
    'address': ['epmloyer', 'adress', 'work']
}

"""Tweede oplossing op stackoverflow"""
"""Loop through the nested list"""

def matches(filter, filename):
    return all(x in filename for x in filter)

def get_filename(filter, files):
    for f in files:
        if matches(filter, f):
            return f

for label, filter in filelist.items():
    file = get_filename(filter, filelist)
    if file:
        print(f'Found {label} file: {file}')
        pass

found_files = {label: get_filename(filter, filelist) for label, filter in filters.items()}
print(found_files)

filenamelist loop --> object bestandsnaam
filter dictory for loop
```

I expect the output to be a list of filenames and their key value.

Comment: Not sure what output you want. Also why do you have `filters` use the same `key` twice?

Comment: Something like this `set(filelist.values()).intersection(set(file_list))` ?

Comment: In the end i need to move the files to specific folders. The name of the folder is the key value of the filter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct you want to create a dictionary. Each key in the dictionary is the name of your filter, and the keys would be a list of filenames that match that filter. Using the code you already have:

```
result = {key: [] for key in filters}

for fil in file_list:
    for f in result:
        if matches(filters[f], fil):
            result[f].append(fil)
```

And in result you'll get this:

```
{'finance': ['01012007-1_employer_finance.txt', '01012011-5_employer_finance.txt01012007-12_employer_finance.txt', '01012011-56_employer_finance.txt'], 
 'manifest': ['25102013-2_cargo_manifest.txt', '25102013-23_cargo_manifest.txt'], 
 'address': ['12022028-4_epmloyer_work_adress.txt', '12022028-45_epmloyer_work_adress.txt']}
```